# SQL query to find out third highest salary involving multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables..

Persons:

```
empid(primary key)
firstname
lastname
email
```

Details:

```
Did(primary key)
salary
designation
empid
```

Now I want to select `firstname`, `lastname`, `salary` of the employee with the 3rd highest salary.

Also it would be great if you can suggest me a site where I can find SQL query exercises with solutions (I do not need an online interpreter, I have SQL Server 2008 to practice on ), I have completed w3schools (which was awesome) but I need exercises now, I tried sql.ex.ru but it was not that helpful.

Comment: I would recommend using SQL Fiddle to practice on: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Kane I think you misread the last part, the poster is looking for exercises with solutions, not websites where he can try things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select firstname, lastname, salary 
 from 
 (
 select 
    employee.*, details.salary,
    row_number() over (order by salary desc) salaryrank
 from 
      employee
 inner join 
      details
           on employee.empid = details.empid
 ) v
 where salaryrank=3
```

As for SQL problems with solutions, why not look on stackoverflow itself? Find a question, and see how you can get an answer. Then see what the best rated answer is

Comment: There is a slight error in your query as employee and details both have the column empid. You need to specify `select employee.*, details.salary, row_number()` in your subquery

Comment: row_number() won't work if  the records have two or more same second highest salary, We can use dense_rank() instead.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if you have tables with the following field values

**Persons**

[image]

**Details**

[image]

Now if you want to find the **Third highest salary**.Then, the query below will give you the following result set.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is the best method as the result(3rd highest salary) might more than 1 row(person).

Answer (score 0):

Find below the answer.

```
select * from empsal e where
3 =(select count(distinct empsal) from empsal where e.empsal<=empsal);
```

Replace '3' with '2' if you need 2nd max salary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.firstname,
    p.lastname, 
    d.salary 
FROM 
    Persons p,
    Details d 
where 
    p.empid=d.empid  
order by 
    d.btID desc 
limit 2,1;
```

Comment: limit does not exists in sql server.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua you can use SELECT TOP to replace LIMIT.